# multiple server_name match fallthrough

Tags: nginx

Given the following configuration shown in pseudo code:

```
// server 1
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name foo-bar.example.com;
    // ...assume no location defined for /hey
}

// server 2
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name *.example.com;

    location /hey {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Nginx will route a request hitting `https://foo-bar.example.com/hey` to server 1 because server 1 has exact match on `server_name`. This results in an error response, because there is not a matching location to match on the URL path `/hey` for server 1. However, there is a matching location to match on `/hey` on server 2.

With this configuration, is there some fallthrough-like configuration parameter that I can configure server 1 with such that the request hitting `https://foo-bar.example.com/hey` would get routed server 2 instead? Note that one constraint is that we cannot define a location block in server 1 that would catch `/hey` on server 1 at all. Is what I'm asking even possible?